# Oracle Weblogic 12c Shutdown not working for two ports

Tags: java, oracle, weblogic, weblogic12c

I have recently turned on SSL port 7003 for my managed server on Weblogic, earlier it was running on non-ssl port 7002. I have disabled non-ssl port by **unchecking  listen port enabled**. Now the Managed Server is only working on SSL port 7003. This is when it gets strange..... I turn off managedserver and I could still see 7003 running (I can access the server on browser). Now I turned off Weblogic (stopWeblogic.sh) and still I can access 7003 port. Can someone explain why on earth is this happening? I went on to a lot of sites and no help.

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the server didn't stop. Check with `netstat -tanp` and see what process is using the port. If it is java, there you are. If you dare (test or production?) do a `kill -9 pid` to get rid of it. I assume you are running on Linux, otherwise there are similar commands for Windows (netstat, task manager or pskill).

Comment: Hi... Thanks for the reply... Yes the server didn't stop... I have found that Managed Server is using the port (which should be the case). I have also tried killing it, as it is the only way to stop the server. However after I kill the application and start the weblogic, and then start managedWeblogic server, the 7003 port automatically gets turned on (Usually I should go to the domains and check the server and then click on start). So it won't stop until I kill the application, and it starts without me me clicking on the start button. Also this is a test server so I can play with it